How to ask Mathematica to find the function period assuming $m$ and $n$ are rationally related?
I have this function
$$  f(x)= \lvert  \sin(m\,x+n\,x)\rvert -\lvert  \sin(m\,x)\rvert\;,$$
in which $\frac mn\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$. Since $m>0$ and $n>0$ are rationally related, the function is periodic with respect to $x$. How can I ask Mathematica to find the function period in terms of $m$ and $n$?
I use the code below but since Mathematica cannot recognize whether $m$ and $n$ are commensurate or not, it does not give an answer.
f[x_]= Abs[Sin[m x+n x]]-Abs[Sin[m x]];

FunctionPeriod[f[x],x]



Not a satisfying answer, but perhaps a workaround.
Rescale x:
rescaled =(Abs[Sin[m x+ n x]]-Abs[Sin[m  x]])/.x->xi/m

Map over a subset of rationals
3 FunctionPeriod[Abs[Sin[xi+ # x]]-Abs[Sin[ xi]],xi,Reals]&/@Range[1,5,1/3]

Or a function
pernm[{n_,m_}]:= Module[{xi},
m  FunctionPeriod[Abs[Sin[xi+ n xi/m]]-Abs[Sin[ xi]],xi]]

E.g.,
pernm[{7,5}]

I can’t see a way to do it generally.
